# Is it good to use a buffer as shader storage buffer and then as atomic counter buffer?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm using an atomic counter which has it's own buffer and i want to clear that counter in some other pass. So is it good to bind the buffer as shader storage buffer to clear it and then, in a second pass use it as atomic counter buffer? Also i would like to ask if it's even ok to use the same buffer as shader storage buffer and as atomic counter buffer at the same time in the same shader, let's say, 4 bytes at the start are intended only for the atomic counter, while in the same buffer is other data which is read/modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same buffer with different targets, but you have to manage alignment requirements yourself (All params for `glGet` with `ALIGNMENT` in their names).

Then you can invalidate a range with `InvalidateBufferSubData` as a performance hint (the GPU doesn't have to preserve content you will clear) and clear the range with `ClearBufferSubData`.

For better performance I would advise using double or triple buffering for the atomic counters, or any data that are often cleared or updated.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by double or triple buffering for the counters. Do you mean using for example 2 buffers for the same counter, which are exchanged on successive shader calls? i don't know how this should improve performance since i need to clear both anyways. Can you tell me how efficient glClearBuffer calls are compared to vertex shaders with one thread, which is just clearing 4 bytes?

Comment: @FamZ: "*Can you tell me how efficient glClearBuffer calls are compared to vertex shaders with one thread, which is just clearing 4 bytes?*" ... what? Think about it. One of these is a simple command. The other is invoking a *rendering process*. Even if the GPU did not have a command specifically for writes to GPU memory, the worst-case would be for the GPU to invoke a compute shader to do the writing. Which will still be *better* than your VS example.

Comment: @FamZ Using multiple buffers means you can clear the next counter while using the current one. Since the two counters are independent to one another, the implementation doesn't have to wait on the counter being cleared before doing operations on it.

Comment: So if i understand right, if i'm clearing a buffer with a call to glClearBufferData and then launch some shader program that means that it's possible that the buffer isn't cleared in that moment yet. But then, why is there no need to call glMemoryBarrier() after clearing a buffer? i'm sorry for asking such questions but i don't know exactly how stuff like that is working...

Comment: `glMemoryBarrier` is only necessary for shader writes. Host writes are visible for subsequent operations, except non-coherent mappings which need `glUnmapBuffer` or `glFlushMappedBufferRange`.